# Shared HashMap in Jetty

Tags: java, hashmap, jetty, concurrenthashmap

I'm currently building a simple REST interface using Jersey with embedded Jetty.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
ServletContextHandler  servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
servletContextHandler.addServlet(sh, "/*");
server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.package.containing.jersey.resource");
```

In my resource I define `@GET, @PUT, @DELETE` methods, which all get/put/remove objects from a hashmap.

Currently I'm defining the `HashMap` as a static `ConcurrentHashMap` in my resource class, which works fine so far.

```
public class MyResource {

private static final Map<String, MyObjects> myRepository = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObjects>();

@GET
...

@PUT
...

}
```

However, I plan to make the `HashMap` accessible for potential other resources and servlets.
 Therefore want to add it in some wider scope application context.
 **Not sure though, how this can be best done?**
 Ideally programatically.
 (I've seen there's a WebAppContext in jetty.webapp, not sure if this is the way to go though).

Comment: No, I don't need persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some dependency injection in your application (Spring, Guice) to inject one instance of the hashmap in all resources needing to access/modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to add an additional framework, just for simply widen the accessibility of one resource.

Comment: Then do it without DI or framework, back to the Singleton: private static final myRepository = MyHashmap.getInstance() wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks, that would do for now. However not my preferred solution, since I don't want all classes to be able to get hold of the HashMap, but limit the scope to all Servlets. I'm still looking for the solution to add it to some server context, if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think the jetty WebAppContext is meant to provide components to your classes, like a Spring application context. It is a JEE Web application context: it knows your context path, web.xml etc.